# Webcam driver that uses an image or video file as the video source

Tags: windows, video, webcam

Does anyone know of software that is recognized as a webcam/video device in Windows and lets you pick an image (JPEG, etc) or video (MPEG/AVI) as the video source?

Idea being that you could do something like a Skype call and instead of having your webcam video you could broadcast an image or prerecorded video instead.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[SplitCamera](http://www.splitcamera.com/) should work for what you need - Free alternative of [ManyCam](http://www.manycam.com).

Comment: Other possibilities: http://www.fakewebcam.com/, http://altercam/

Comment: SplitCamera worked for me when I needed to use Facebook Messenger Rooms but I didn't have  a webcam to connect to.

Comment: The link is not currently working and when I search for it I only get a "SplitCam" which doesn't look like a driver but as a streaming app like OBS. Is this it? Was it renamed?

Answer (score 9):

Came across this and thought I would contribute the solution that suited my needs.

[**Open Broadcaster Studio**](https://obsproject.com/) allows you to stream and record many sources layed out in a virtual canvas: you can define sources such as :

- Images, Video, Your Live Desktop, your microphone, Audio Files, your speaker output, ...

Additionally you will **Require** a plugin To be able to create a Virtual WebCam:

- [**OBS-VirtualCam**](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.949/) provides a directshow Output as a virtual webcam of the virtual canvas which you have defined from the selected sources.

  - The plugin works on Windows.
  - For Linux, you can use the [Video4Linux](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink) sink plugin for OBS Studio.

Once installed, setup and running: select the ***OBS-camera*** source from the webcams available from within the software of your choice.

Cheers!