# Is it possible to crop the webcam video on Linux?

Tags: linux, video, webcam

Because of the increasing number of virtual meetings I upgraded my setup and purchased a new webcam (*Logitech C920s HD Pro Webcam*). The image quality is great, but the viewing angle is much wider than with my previous (built-in) one.

That's okay for personal use, but for business calls I would like to limit it so not the entire room is visible.
Is it possible to crop the image on Linux (*Manjaro Gnome*)? Especially on the sides, top/bottom is okay.

I would be great if it can be done on a system level, so it works with all the major video conferencing platforms (jitsi, zoom, google, skype, ...).

Comment: I think that there is a "virtual camera" output or plugin for [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) that you could use. Basically feed in your camera, do whatever cropping/processing you need and then feed it out as a "standard" camera. Not 100% sure if I'm misremembering and don't have any specific instructions hence only a comment rather than an answer. Related question that might be useful, mentions the virtual camera output: https://superuser.com/questions/681386/webcam-driver-that-uses-an-image-or-video-file-as-the-video-source?rq=1

Comment: I assume that would work, unfortunately I couldn't get it set up on my system yet